# Callback function and void pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, callback, void, void-pointers

```
ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues
(
int16_t handle,
ps3000aStreamingReady lpPs3000AReady,
void * pParameter
)
```

1. `lpPs3000AReady`, a pointer to your `ps3000aStreamingReady` callback function
2. `pParameter`, a `void` pointer that will be passed to the `ps3000aStreamingReady` callback. The callback may optionally use this pointer to return information to the application.

And here is the `ps3000aStreamingReady` callback function:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *ps3000aStreamingReady)
(
int16_t handle,
int32_t noOfSamples,
uint32_t startIndex,
int16_t overflow,
uint32_t triggerAt,
int16_t triggered,
int16_t autoStop,
void * pParameter
)
```

My question is how I can declare `pParameter` in my main function? `pParameter` use as a communicator between those two functions and it's a `void` pointer because it might have to pass any kinds of data.Somehow I have to allocate memory before pass this void pointer as a arguments on those function. But how can do that?

Comment: What do you need the `void*` parameter to contain?

Comment: * pParameter, a void pointer passed from ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues.ps3000aStreamingReady  callback function can write
to this location to send any data, such as a status flag, back to the
application.

Comment: `void* userData` is the C-way to capture extra data, C++ way with `std::function` allow capturing lambda and even custom functor.

Comment: You can pass a pointer to (almost) anything as a parameter that is declared as `void*`. And you can add an explicit cast (in the function call) if you really want to.

Comment: @AnikIslam which parameters do you need to get from `pParameter` so that you can call `lpPs3000AReady`?

Comment: lpPs3000AReady is a function pointer of ps3000aStreamingReady(), and pParameter use as a information exchanger between ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues() and ps3000aStreamingReady()....mainly ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues() this API sent the void pointer (pParameter ) to the ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues() call back function.So that ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues() function can write any kinds of data and sent it back to ps3000aGetStreamingLatestValues(). wichout knowing the type how I can allocate memory for pParameter?because the data type will be decided by the call back function.

Comment: @AnikIslam you have to allocate the known type where you decide which callback is going to be called, or add another function pointer that will allocate the known type when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional C-way for callback to allow extra parameter is to have extra `void*` that user provides.

```
using callback = bool (int, int, void* userData);

struct CallBack
{
    bool operator ()(int a, int b) { /*..*/ }

    // extra members ...
};

bool run_callback(int a, int b, void* userData) {
    CallBack* c = reinterpret_cast<CallBack*>(userData);

    return (*c)(a, b);
}
```

with possible usage:

```
CallBack t(true); // Care to lifetime, should still be there when `run_callback` is called
Register(&run_callback, &t); // Would call later run_callback(2, 3, &t);
```

If you don't need that extra parameter, you might pass your regular function and `nullptr`

```
bool run_callback(int a, int b, void*) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
Register(&run_callback, nullptr); // Would call later run_callback(2, 3, nullptr);
```

For C++ way of type erasure, you might use `std::function`.